# The chocolate chips in my chocolate chip cookies dont rise to the top

Tags: baking, chocolate, cookies

Why does my chocolate chip cookies look "ugly"? The chocolate chips stay insdie the cookies, unlike other chocolate chip cookies, the choco chips go are on top of the cookies and look so good. I just followed the recipe. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think they are supposed to rise to the top. If you are looking at a picture in a recipe or book, the chips were probably placed in that position for appeal. You can do the same before cooking by placing a few chips on top. Advertising is a deceptive busines!

Comment: Ahh, okay! Thank you so much. I will try putting some chips on top to see if I get the same result.